# Does Vim emulation for Visual Studio supports plugins?

Tags: vsvim

And if so, how can I install them. I've manged it for gVIM, but can't get it working in VsVim.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't, it has only limited support for vimscript. And as @jaredpar explais at https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/issues/1474#issuecomment-60990979 it is not planned.